# Jasper reports : How to repeat table header in each pages

Tags: jasper-reports

I am working with jasper report where some tables i am using to show data as usual. I want to repeat my table's header in every page. I know column header will resolve my requirement but still i want to repeat table header instead of column header. is that possible?

I need to show two header i mean first two row will be header of that table. i was thinking if i can use table header and column header both and can repeat both in every page.. Plz help if anyone already face same things

Comment: Are you using *jr:table* component?

Comment: yes using jr:table and making jrxml design using jaspersoft studio 6.11.0

Answer (score 1):

Actually i got a way which meet my requirements. jaspersoft studio has a option to create group header which is available under table's dataset. there i have created a group and got an property "Reprint header on each page" check mark that option then added columns under that group in table section.

And finally its working properly as i was expecting.. thanks for your time